# How to Remove Character ↵ in between two words of JavaScript String?

Tags: javascript, replace

If I select two lines together and get text using `window.getSelection().toString()` then I get  `↵` in between two words (last word from the upper line, and the first word of the lower word). Below is my code-

```
document.addEventListener('dblclick',function (event) {

var element = document.getElementsByClassName(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.className);


var T= window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=500");

T.document.write(element[0].innerText.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"));


T.document.write(`<script>
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
if(e.keyCode === 16) {
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection) {
text_1 = window.getSelection().toString();
text = text_1.replace(/\u21b5/g," "); // my attempt to corrrect
                        } 
words = text.split(" ");
console.log(words);
}
},false);
</script>`);
},false);
```

For example, if I select -

> Sides
>
> Section

and press shift key I get  -

```
Array(1)
0: "Sides↵Section"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

but the out put should be-

```
Array(1)
0: "Sides Section"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

How can I replace `↵` with space?

PS: I have tried some possibilities based on solutions given on SE, but it didn't work, plz don't consider it trivial or duplicate post.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: I have tried, but didn't get the result I wanted

Comment: That is just how the newline character is displayed, there are many ways to remove it. Try `variable.replace("\n", " ")`

Comment: @GammaGames I tried that to, you can check yourself, that does not work, I do't know the reason why!

Comment: @Mike people are trying to be helpful and your comments can be read as being rude.

Comment: Debug it and see what the return characters are. `console.log(escape(text_1))`

Comment: @epascarello whicj comment is rude? let me know i'll delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace new lines and carriage returns and then replace empty spaces.

```
window.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 16) {
      var text = "";
      if (window.getSelection) {
        text_1 = window.getSelection().toString();
        text = text_1
                .replace(/\n|\r/g, " ")
                .replace(/\s/, "");
      }
        words = text.split(" ");
        console.log(words);
    }
  },
  false
);
```

Comment: I think using `trim` before replacing would be a better solution than filtering after

Comment: @GammaGames Changed the code to two `replace`s. `trim` doesn't work in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to replace new lines **and** carriage returns

So something like this:

```js
text = text_1.trim().replace(/[\n\r]/g, ' ');
```

**UPDATE**

```js
// Solution from code sample 

  T.document.write(`<script>
    window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 16) {
        if (window.getSelection) {
          const text = window.getSelection().toString();
          const words = text.trim().replace(/\r?\n/g, " ");
          console.log(words);
        }
      }
  });
  </script>`);
```

Comment: Plz use my complete code, and see whether it works or not, I have tried  your line but it didn't work

Comment: @Mike are you able to provide a fiddle or code sandbox of the code that is ***not*** working in your example and I can add my changes to that

Comment: you copy my code and put it in inspect->console it will run... I tried your code but it didn't work, plz change my complete code, also I am new so i am not familiar with the things you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace \n and \r\n with space. Depending which one the OS uses. 
If you don't want to bother with OS check then replace \r\n first then \n.

**UPDATE:**

The code is: `text = text_1.replace(/\r?\n/g, " ");`

Comment: could you plz put it to above code and check whether it works or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `\s+` (any whitespace of one or more characters) with `" "`. You can also split on the same regex, if that was your goal.

```js
document.addEventListener('select', () => {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
    words = text.trim().replace(/\s+/g, " ");
    console.log(words);
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea rows=4>
foo
bar
</textarea>
```